# WooCommerce template page for category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

How do I change the WordPress template used for the WooCommerce category pages?

I can change the product pages by using the single-product.php template, but the category pages just use **page.php** which I don't want to modify because it is so sidely used.

How do I modify this template and only affect category pages? I am **NOT** interested in overriding the WooCommerce templates, I want to edit the surrounding template that contains the header, footer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and the solution is this

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce categories are called `product_cat`. If you check the [WP template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), you see that for (custom) taxonomy archives, `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` works.

So in your case, creating a `taxonomy-product_cat.php` should work.

You can copy the content from taxonomy.php, archive.php or index.php and start your work from there.

Comment: This is what I thought, but it is using the page template. This suggests that it isn't an archive page at all.

Comment: @WilliamOakley Please check my update, I mixed up category (which is a specific taxonomy) and taxonomies in general. With this it worked on my local install with WooCommerce. If it doesn't, can you post the HTML classes `<body>` has?

Comment: body classes: woocommerce woocommerce-page woocommerce-js

Comment: No `archive` in there? Then it really is not the page for the category, but just a regular page (that may retrieve posts via shortcode, custom theme functionality). You can use `page-$slug.php` or `page-$id.php` then for this specific page